# where to find statistics about .net developers worldwide

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am looking for some statistics about .net developers which works with vs 2008 and language c#, worldwide.

Is it possible to find such specific information?
If someone has actual information, at least 2 years young, please help me.

And one thing more: I preffer to have charge free information:)!

Comment: Exactly what kind of statistics are you looking for? This is a terribly vague request at the moment.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010 and C#. There you go, that’s your first statistic with a sample size of *n* = 1 ☺

Comment: So helpful.....is that the best you can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say stackoverflow itself represents the best source of raw data.

I'd get the commons licensed data dump and mine that.

Comment: I think StackOverflow is a really bad representation of developers worldwide. Firstly, it is English-centric. Secondly, it attracts amateur/hobby programmers more than busy professionals. Thirdly, the StackOverflow reputation system doesn’t reflect programming ability by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: The numbers suggest that it's a pretty meaningful chunk of developers.  Lots of details, like reputation, that you're free to ignore if you wish.  The OP gave no requirements about amateur versus professional or the need for reputation.  And you've failed to offer any alternative that would be better.  Your down vote is unwarranted, in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest that you try Gartner. It's an IT analyst company with very valuable information (but not for free)

http://www.gartner.com/technology/home.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I find itjobswatch has a lot of useful information. Not sure if it's quite what you're after though

http://www.itjobswatch.co.uk/ 
http://www.itjobswatch.co.uk/jobs/uk/csharp.do